# how to disable past date in tapx-datefield

Tags: java, web, tapestry, datefield

hi im using tapx datefield date picker in my tapestry project, and i want to disable past dates so user cannot select past dates, how can i do that, i have tried several method and discover that tapx-datefield has max and min parameter inside its class, but i have no idea how to set it. can anybody help me with this ? thanks for any help

[image: this is the parameter i said above]

Comment: Component parameters can be passed via attributes, i.e. `<t:DateField max="myMaxDate" min="myMinDate" ... />` -- is it not working? It looks like a regular component https://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html

Comment: Wow it worked, thankyou so much ! That was so simple and straightforward

Comment: Cool, now post the solution as your own answer and accept it to collect some points @GonoGini :)

Comment: Okay , thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component parameters can be passed via attributes, i.e. <t:DateField max="myMaxDate" min="myMinDate" ... /> , thanks to Dimitry Gusev comment, so you just have to create a date variable and pass it ..... for example

```
Date td = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(td);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    td = c.getTime(); //TODO> Tomorrow Date 

maxDate = td;
```